# How to call a function in one angular component from another component(different .ts file)

Tags: angular, typescript, function, web-frontend, viewchild

File1.ts

```
export class1(){
      dummy(a,b){
        ....
}
}
```

File2.ts

```
export class2(){ 
     a: string = "scjhb"
     b: string ="mn hbh"
     //From here,I want to call dummy pass these parameters and call dummy function from file1.ts.How to do?
     dummy(a,b); //I want to call dummmy(a,b)    
}

i tried the below thing in File2.ts,but it's not working.
```

@ViewChild(class1, { static: false }) Classvar: class1;
this.Classvar.dummy(a,b)

Comment: You need to import the file. I'd recommend another glance at the documentation.

Comment: I had imported as well
```import {class1} from ./File1
```

Comment: Have you tried instantiating the imported class in File2.ts with the `new` keyword?

Comment: You could then simply call class1.dummy(a,b)

Comment: Isn't there any other way than instantiating? .Because in constructor,I need to pass many things in the real code.I am looking for non-instantiating ways.

Comment: Yes, either don't make it a class, use static methods if you really want to use `class`, or export a new instance instead of the class itself.

Comment: Are the two components related to each other?

Comment: It's a big codebase.In this question I put forth the simplified version.

The components are directly not related,but I need to call function of another componenet for a task

Comment: @Phix , can u plz write the linew of code ?

Comment: If there is a direct parent / child relationship you could do this. However, it’s quite a bad idea. Use a service for shared functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply extends another class[inheritance].

Providing Stackblitz example: [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-smdmzp?file=src/app/app.component.ts)